# jpa - create Map<String, List<String>> field with one table

Tags: java, jpa

I have a table with columns `map_id, key, value`.
Values looks like `1, key1, value1` `1, key1, value2` `2, map2, value1`, etc.
Is it possible to create entity like this:

```
class MapEntity {
 Integer map_id;
 Map<String, List<String>> values;
}
```

or maybe

```
class MapEntity {
 Integer map_id;
 Map<String, Values> values;
}

class Values {
  ..something
  List<String> values;
}
```

?

Comment: Nope. Can't be done. Your table has no PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with following solution:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "map_holder")
public class MapHolder {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "map_id")
  public Integer mapId;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "map_id")
  @MapKey(name = "recordKey")
  public Map<String, MapRecord> values = new HashMap<>();

  public MapHolder() {

  }

  public MapHolder(Integer mapId) {
    this.mapId = mapId;
  }

  public void put(String key, String value) {
    if(values.containsKey(key)) {
      values.get(key).add(value);
    } else {
      MapRecord mr = new MapRecord();
      mr.mapId = mapId;
      mr.recordKey = key;
      mr.recordValue = value;
      values.put(key, mr);
    }
  }
}
```

This is an entity that will hold reference to map.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "map_record",
  uniqueConstraints= @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"map_id", "record_key", "record_value"}))
public class MapRecord {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "record_id", columnDefinition = "INTEGER NOT NULL")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public  Integer recordId;

    @Column(name = "map_id")
    public  Integer mapId;

    @Column(name = "record_key")
    public  String recordKey;

    @Column(name = "record_value")
    public  String recordValue;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "record_key", referencedColumnName = "record_key")
    public List<MapRecord> values = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(String value) {
        MapRecord mr = new MapRecord();
        mr.mapId = mapId;
        mr.recordKey = recordKey;
        mr.recordValue = value;
        values.add(mr);
    }
}
```

And this entity for data.

```
MapHolder mh = new MapHolder(1);
mh.put("key1", "value1");
mh.put("key1", "value2");
em.persist(mh);
```

And finally usage.

Note: seems like joints on non primary key like in MapRecord is up to JPA impl, and in some cases it will not work properly. On Eclipselink this code works pretty good.

Comment: Is this working for you ? In my case there is no insert happnes for `MapRecord` table. No exception either.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement second option. Create Values class with String key and a list of values. In MapEntity class use `@OneToMany` and `@MapKey` to define the relationship:

**MapEntity:**

```
class MapEntity {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private Integer map_id;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy="mapentity")
     @MapKey(name="key")
     private  Map<String, Keys> values;
    }
```

**Keys:**

```
 public class Keys{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Integer id;

        @ManyToOne
        private MapEntity mapEntity;
        @Column(name="key")
        private String key;
        @ManyToMany
        private List<String> values;
    }
```

**Tables:**

Need 3 tables:

`MapEntity`(Employee)

`Keys`(ProjectType) to associate keys with MapEntities

`Keys_values` (PROJECTTYPE_PROJECT) to associate keys with values

**Check this example:** https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Collections.2C_Maps_and_Matrices

Comment: but... will it work for one table, as described in question?

Comment: You need second class to represent the association.

Comment: any examples, how to map columns, how to specify table?

Comment: Edited with example

Comment: the question was "with one table", not 3. Sorry, but your answer not correct :(